# helm install with --set ends in an error "v1.ObjectMeta.Annotations: ReadString: expects " or n, but found t, error found in #10 byte"

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to run a helm chart with:

```
helm upgrade --install artifactory-int --set ingress.annotations.'kubernetes\.io\/tls-acme'="true"
```

But this drops an error message:

```
Ingress in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a Ingress: v1beta1.Ingress.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.Annotations: ReadString: expects " or n, but found t, error found in #10 byte of ...|ls-acme":true},"labe|..., bigger context ...|tadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/tls-acme":true},"labels":{"app":"artifactory","chart":"artifa|...
```

The error message is expecting **"** or **n**

When configuring values.yaml (see following code lines) --> everything works fine,...

```
ingress:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
```

...but I want to set the parameter with "--set" within the helm install command instead of manipulating the values.yaml

**The ingress template is giving me the folloing information:**

```
metadata:
{{- if .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ .Values.ingress.annotations | toYaml | trimSuffix "\n" | indent 4 -}}
{{- end }}
```

**I tried several variatons of set, some of them passed the "ReadString" issue, but ingress annotaion is not set correctly.**

## some examples

```
--set ingress.annotations.'kubernetes\.io\/tls-acme'=true'"'
-->
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: true"

--set ingress.annotations.'kubernetes\.io\/tls-acme'="true\n"
-->
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: truen

--set ingress.annotations.'kubernetes\.io\/tls-acme'='\"true\"'
-->
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: '"true"'
```

## What is need to be set to get the following results?

```
--set ingress.annotations.'kubernetes\.io\/tls-acme'=???????
-->
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set string forcely you can run following

```
--set-string ingress.annotations.'kubernetes\.io\/tls-acme'="true"
```